# Custom Notification Channel in SonarQube 8.1 plugin

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying write a plugin that will send user notification in a similar manner that the Sonar build-in email notifications.

I would like it to support the latest 8.1 version.  
Looking the source code in github it looks like this is implemented in `EmailNotificationChannel.java` that extends `NotificationChannel.java`
Abstract class.

In the java docs it looks like NotificationChannel is deprecated, but I cannot find any alternative API for such use case.

Any recommendation on the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sonarqube [dropped notification support](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-11753)

> We will **drop usage of this API for built-in notifications**. We will deprecate this API as it is flawed and will continue support it transparently. Whether there will be a **replacement has not been decided yet**.
>
> This way, **it won't run at all unless a non-SonarSource plugin is installed which uses this API and this will fix our performance issue with notification sending**.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. Any alternative until the decision will be made? what do you mean by  it won't run at all unless a non-SonarSource plugin is installed...

Comment: @HaimRaman It's a quote from sonar issue, which state there's currently no replacement